# ATmega328P SPI fails to transmit

Tags: atmega, spi

G'day, I am currently experimenting with the an ATmega328P (on an Arduino, but programmed directly in C *without* the Arduino libraries)  and it's SPI bus for communication with no other devices straight away just watching the data fly pass on my oscilloscope.

But I'm currently having a problem where I can't transmit anything straight after initialising the SPI peripheral. At first I thought it might be a delay problem where I need to wait at least x us/ms between initialising the SPI peripheral and transmitting data but I can't find mention of it in the data sheet. But I am able to get the SPI bus to output data when I put **SPDR** inside an infinite while loop and get it to repeat the same character over and over again.

So my question is how can you force the micro controller to wait until the SPI bus is ready to transmit? Or have I made some other silly error?

```
int main(void)
{
    DDRB = (1 << DDB5) | (1 << DDB3) | (1 << DDB2) | (1 << DDB0);
    PORTB |= 1 << PORTB2;
    SPCR = (1 << SPE) | (1 << MSTR) | (1 << SPR1) | (1 << SPR0);

        PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB2);
        // This doesn't work
        //SPDR = 'A';
        //while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));
        //_delay_ms(1);
        while(1) {
            // This works
            SPDR = 'A';
            while(!(SPSR & (1 <<  SPIF)));
            _delay_ms(1);
        }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the first attempt which you commented out does not work?  Catching one-time events can be tricky, requiring careful use of a storage scope or logic analyzer or similar - and doubly so if they happen right after reset when lines may first be driven as outputs.

Comment: You could also consider writing incrementing numbers out in the loop; then if you really are seeing what you think you're seeing, the first number you see will give a good indication of how many 'lost' bytes there are.